# How to get the cursor position in google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Is there any Google Apps Script API to get the cursor position. I am able to read the line using getcursor() method but I want to know the position of the cursor. If anyone knows about this case please help me.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is what you want, how about ``getOffset()``? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/position#getOffset()